# Style staticResource in Express 2013 for windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I wan to change style myButton
so but when I come to add, a message show: the resource "AppBarButtonStyle" could not be resolved.
and I discover that it just support three templates:

- NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle
- NavigationBackButtonSmallStyle
- TextBlockButtonStyle

How can I add app bar button styles or some element the same AppBarButtonStyle in Express 2013 for windows

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the `ResourceDictionary` holding your `Style` is Visible in the Controls Scope;

Try this :

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml"/> <!--Basically your path to the ResourceDictionary-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
     </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Change the `YourAssembly` to your your assembly's name which holds the style.

Hope it helps :)